# How to SNI filter with nftables v1.0.8?

Tags: nftables, https

eg: permit classroom and block youtube which share an IP:

```
dig www.youtube.com +short | grep "$(dig classroom.google.com +short)"
142.251.32.78
```

https://serverfault.com/questions/988309/filter-on-bytes-in-udp-payload-using-nftables#988614

and

https://blog.cloudflare.com/programmable-packet-filtering-with-magic-firewall

seem related.

Comment: In my linked answer I wrote "as long as its in fixed locations (you won't get the variable position features of iptables' string match, nor all of iptables' u32 match features".  SNI dosn't follow this restriction, so my answer can't be used for SNI. You should consider using a proxy with two features: transparent proxy + SNI passthrough. I believe squid, haproxy or nginx might have these two features.

Comment: @A.B Any idea how to do it with ebpf instead f a proxy?